# How to copy a field from a .gz file to a csv

Tags: python, windows, csv, batch-file, cmd

Is there a way to copy a field, from a .gz file into a txt file without unzipping in either Windows commands or Python?

- The .gz file is over 15000 lines long
- If field 1="SVR" i need to output fields 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 11, 12, 13 and 21. (if $1 = other, ignore)
- Can be written to any other file type, does not have to be txt.

Comment: Switch to Linux and use `zgrep` and `cut`.

Comment: Python comes with the [`gzip` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html#module-gzip) which can read files compressed that way. However there's really no way to avoid reading the file to find the field values you want. Sorry, I don't understand what "$1 = other" means in the context of your question.

Comment: pippy5: Why have you tagged your question with "python" if you don't want to use it?

Comment: Can I output using zgrep and cut though?

The "if $1 = other, ignore" just means that if field 1 is not SVR I don't want to use it. 
I do want to use python- I am after it either DOS OR PYTHON. I can make either work. Thanks.

Comment: @pippy5, I can guarantee you are not using `DOS`. Winzip's command line client can essentially do what you want but it is not a free program.  Not sure if 7zip can do it or not.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using Python's gzip library to read the `.gz` file, the `csv` library to parse the CSV file inside and the use of `operator.itemgetter()` to extract the required items from each row:

```
from operator import itemgetter
import csv
import gzip

with gzip.open('input.gz', 'rb') as f_gz, open('output.csv', 'wb') as f_output:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_gz)
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    req_cols = itemgetter(1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 10, 11, 12, 20)
    csv_output.writerow(req_cols(next(csv_input)))

    for row in csv_input:
        if row[0] == 'SVR':
            csv_output.writerow(req_cols(row))
```

So if you had a CSV containing something like:

```
c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9,c10,c11,c12,c13,c14,c15,c16,c17,c18,c19,c20,c21,c22
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22
SVR,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22
3,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22
SVR,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22
```

You would get an output CSV file containing:

```
c2,c3,c4,c6,c7,c11,c12,c13,c21
2,3,4,6,7,11,12,13,21
2,3,4,6,7,11,12,13,21
```

Tested on Python 2.x. For Python 3.x, the files would need to be opened as:

```
with gzip.open('input.gz', 'rt', newline='') as f_gz, open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
```

Comment: Thanks Martin Evans- I am recieving the follow error....   File "D:\Temp\20171203\split.py", line 37, in <module>
    csv_output.writerow(req_cols(next(csv_input)))
IndexError: list index out of range>


I am using python 2.7.9

Comment: Is the first row in your file blank (or does not have 22 values) ? The code assumes that it has a header as I have shown in my example. If it does not have a header, you need to remove that line.

Comment: Ohhh okay, I see. Thanks- sorry i am only a newbie. Thanks